# Why would and img onerror handler execute if image works fine

Tags: javascript, html, image, error-handling

I have implemented the onerror attribute for some images in order to detect the ones that are missing in my site.

**This is the code:**

```
<script>
    function imageError(element) {
        var noPicUrl = "${noPicUrl}";
        var imageFailUrl = "/site/image/fail?mediaUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(element.src) + "&redirectUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(noPicUrl);

        element.onerror = "";
        element.src = imageFailUrl;
    }
</script>

<img src="${poiPic}" onerror="imageError(this);"/>
```

As you can see, when an image fails, then the following url is called:

`/site/image/fail?mediaUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(element.src) + "&redirectUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(noPicUrl)`

This is a service that saves the mediaUrl that failed so that then I can check those and returns a redirect to the redirectUrl. That is working just fine. I just tested it and it logs perfectly.

But the problem was when I uploaded this to production and the logs started.. There where like 200 images in the log. But only 4 of them were really deleted and the link didn't work. The other ones just worked perfectly..

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are there any errors that show up? What about your code is not working in production?

Comment: @Flynn There are no errors, the code works fine in production (at least for me and some other users).. There has been too much more than 200 images loaded, like 10000. And those loaded fine.

Answer (score 0):

Image loading errors are difficult to manage because sometime error occoured fr cache problem, something for connection, other time is due to 404 error. Different browser manage these errors in a lot of way

IMHO the best way to manage image loading errors is to use the ImagesLoaded plugin of jquery

http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/